# Can I Add a new KeyValuePair into a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, double, keyvaluepair

I didn't know how to ask the question.

I have this variable:

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>> Variable
```

Can I have different "Values" in a specific Key? For Example:

```
Variable<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>>(10, new KeyValuePair<int string> {100, William; 460, John; 100, Daniel})
```

So that Variable[Key] has diferent Values

```
Variable[10][100, William]
Variable[10][460, John]
Variable[10][100, Daniel]
```

I tried adding them with the same key but it didn't let me

I don't know if that is possible, and if so, how can I add values and how to look for values with a `foreach` loop?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No there is only on _value_ per _key_. But you could create a `Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>>` and fill the lists per key.

Comment: <3 This is what I was looking for, thank you, makes sense, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

In a Dictionary you can't have more than one value with the same key. What you could do, is create a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` (string is an example, could be anything)

Comment: So will it save something like: List[0][100, William], List[0][460, John], List[0][100, Daniel]?

Comment: @RodolfoContreras Well, for that you have to use as René point out in his comment, to have the list inside the dictionary, so you could keep your `10` index for all the three elements. Then you could access like this `dicName[10][0]` and it would return [100,William], `dicName[10][1]` [460,John], and so on.

Comment: Thank you @Magnetron <3 I will try this, and thanks for helping me out on how to fetch the values!